# Inverse matrix in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
    transpose([A|As], At) :-
       transpose(A, [A|As], At).

    transpose([], _, []).
    transpose([_|As], Rest, [At|Ats]) :-
       first_column(Rest, At, NewRest),
       transpose(As, NewRest, Ats).

    first_column([], [], []).
    first_column([[A|As]|Ass], [A|Acc], [As|Rest]) :-
       first_column(Ass, Acc, Rest).
```

Here is a function that returns the transposed matrix. How can I write a function that gives me the inverse matrix?

Comment: Prolog doesn't have functions. Functions return things. Prolog has predicates. Predicates either succeed or fail. If you've got a bit of time on your hands try unraveling this: http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?inverse+matrix/mskzzzz_1180185539&pro

Comment: Where did that code come from? By "inverse matrix" do you mean the multiplicative inverse? Are you familiar with the formula for computing the multiplicative inverse?

Comment: That code came from my professor. And about the formula for computing the multiplicative inverse, yes I do, but I don't know how to implement this in prolog.

Comment: Thanks about the explanation, Enigmativity, I'm new in Prolog.

Comment: Are you really tasked with implementing this for an arbitrary matrix, or do you only have to handle 2x2 or 3x3 matrices?

Comment: Above code succeeds for `transpose([[a],[b|non_list]],[[a,b]]).` Was this intended?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the general case kind of sucks, and there are [lots of algorithms to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion).

However, the 2x2 case is very simple:

```
invert([[A,B],[C,D]], [[IA,IB],[IC,ID]]) :-
    Det is A*D-B*C,
    Det \= 0,
    IDet is 1/Det,
    IA is IDet*D, IB is IDet*(-B),
    IC is IDet*(-C), ID is IDet*A.
```

The `Det \= 0` test is important, because not every matrix has an inverse.

Comment: Is it possible to give Prolog just the info that the inverse times the matrix is the identity matrix, an let Prolog find it?

Comment: @RainerGlüge I don't know enough about matrix math to answer you.

Comment: I found that prolog can not infer in  arithmetics.

Comment: @RainerGlüge Are you sure? [clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) can do a lot, I just don't know if it can do what you are asking.

Comment: I am pretty sure. Here (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.31.1390&rep=rep1&type=pdf) it says that "Prolog handles arithmetic the way Fortran did thirty years ago: the unknown
can only be a single variable on the left of the operator is , and everything
on the right must be known. Thus
?- X is 2 + 2.
gets the answer 4 , but
?- X is 1 + 1 / X.
fails or raises an error condition."

Comment: @RainerGlüge `clpfd` can do quite a bit more than built-in Prolog arithmetic, please consult the linked documentation. 1989 is a long time ago.

Comment: `clpfd` extends the capabilities of prolog to infer also in integer arithmetic. This is pretty powerful, but inverse matrices are not covered by this.

Comment: I also found [another implementation](http://colin.barker.pagesperso-orange.fr/lpa/gauss.htm) of Gauss-Jordan elimination in Prolog, which can be used to find the inverse of a matrix.